# ADD role from database1 to another role from database2 in SQL Server 2016

Tags: roles

I am trying to optimize permissions: whenever I use the role "ROLE1", I also have to use `sp_sendmail` from MSDB.

How to assign `sp_sendmail` to a role in another SQL Server database?